# Implementing a compressed trie tree "add" function

Tags: java

I'm trying to write an compressed trie tree code in Java and I'm not sure how to start implementing the "compress" of the tree.

My node class consist of an array of size 27 and a String.

```
public class TrieNode {
    TrieNode [] array;
    String data;
}
```

Should I write a regular trie then create a function which compresses my nodes?

Comment: There are lots of approaches to compressing tries. (See, for instance, the [Wikipedia topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Compressing_tries).) What are you trying to accomplish? Also, your question is far too broad. StackOverflow is appropriate for asking about specific programming problems. Before posting here, you need to try something and explain where you are stuck. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more about how to ask questions. Also see [this meta thread](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start).

Comment: See [Compressed tries (Patricia tries)](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Text/trie02.html).